# How to properly index, and chose the best primary key for MySQL InnoDB table

Tags: mysql, innodb

This is my fist time with big MySQL tables, and i have a couple of questions about the speed of a search.

I have a table with 100 million entries in a MySQL table. The table now look like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Accession | char(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| DB        | char(6)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Organism  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Gene      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Name      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Header    | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Sequence  | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

with indexes like this:

```
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| uniprot |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | Accession   | A         |    94275840 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| uniprot |          1 | main_index |            1 | Accession   | A         |    94275840 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| uniprot |          1 | main_index |            2 | DB          | A         |    94275840 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| uniprot |          1 | main_index |            3 | Organism    | A         |    94275840 |      191 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| uniprot |          1 | main_index |            4 | Gene        | A         |    94275840 |      191 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| uniprot |          1 | main_index |            5 | Name        | A         |    94275840 |      191 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

My question is about the efficiency of this. The searces i use are very simple, but i need the answer really fast.
For 80% of the times i use Accession as a query and i want the sequence back.

```
select sequence from uniprot where accession="q32p44";
...
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

For 10% of the times i search for a "Gene" and 10% of the time i search for an Organism.

The table is unique for "Accession".

My questions are:

Can i make this table more efficient (search time wise) anyhow?

Is the indexing good?

Do i speed up the search time by making a multiple keyed primary key like (Accession, Gene, Organism)?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT1:

As requested in the comments:

```
mysql> show create table uniprot;
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table   | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| uniprot | CREATE TABLE `uniprot` (
  `Accession` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `DB` char(6) NOT NULL,
  `Organism` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Gene` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Header` text NOT NULL,
  `Sequence` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Accession`),
  KEY `main_index`              (`Accession`,`DB`,`Organism`(191),`Gene`(191),`Name`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you post the `show create table uniprot`? Also, why are you not using an int primary key? It stands to reason that a 10 byte varchar PK will not be as performant as a 4 byte int PK with big datasets.

Comment: Indexes can speed up reading from your table, but they'll always slow down writing to it.  What indexes you need/want will depend on the exact queries you're seeking to perform, and how you evaluate the tradeoff between read/write performance.  If you're only ever filtering by a single column, then composite indexes such as `(Accession, Gene, Organism)` won't help (unless it's a covering index, in which case the results can be retrieved from the index file without resorting to the table content; e.g. `(Accession, Sequence)` for the example query given above).

Comment: @eggyal Thanks, i guess for 95% of the time i search for a single column. How can i improve the table then?

Comment: @MikePurcell I ll edit the post soon for "show create table uniprot". I dont really understand why i would need an INT for a table like this, as non of the columns contain pure INTs. Why would it be beneficial for me?

Comment: @GáborErdős: There are several online resources explaining why a surrogate key > natural key with regards to establishing a primary key.

Comment: @GáborErdős as @eggyal mentioned, you need to determine your most used queries, and determine which column(s) they are using to return result sets. Based on these queries you can then start adding indices to improve performance. That `main_index` index is pretty painful, typically if you are going to trim a column to X number of chars, it's short, say < 10, just enough to lower the number of rows which need to be considered, 191 chars seems way too high.

Comment: I think i pretty well determined my queries in the post. 80% of the time i use Accession as a search parameter and i need a sequence back. I even described the rest 20%

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "prefix" indexing, it almost never does as well as you might expect.

`CHAR(10)` with `utf8mb4` means that you are taking 40 bytes always.  `accession="q32p44"` implies `VARCHAR` and `ascii` would be better.  With those changes, I would not bother switching to a 'surrogate' key.  Consider the same issue for `DB`.

With `PRIMARY KEY(Accession)` and InnoDB, there is no advantage in having `KEY main_index (Accession, ...)`.  Drop that `KEY`.

What is `Sequence`?  If it is a text string with only 4 different letters, then it should be highly compressible.  And, with 100M rows, shrinking the disk footprint could lead to a noticeable speedup.  I would `COMPRESS` it in the client and store it into a `BLOB`.

Do you really need 255 in `varchar(255)`?  Please shrink to something 'reasonable' for the data.  That way, we can reconsider what index(es) to add, without using prefixing.

```
select sequence from uniprot where accession="q32p44";
```

works very efficiently with `PRIMARY KEY(accession)`

```
select sequence from uniprot where accession="q32p44" AND gene = '...';
```

also works efficiently with that PK.  It will find the *one* row for q32p44 and then simply check that `gene` matches; then deliver 0 or 1 row.

```
select sequence from uniprot where gene = '...';
```

would benefit from `INDEX(gene)`.  Similarly for `Organism`.

How big is the table (in GB)?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?  If the table is a lot bigger than the buffer pool, a random "point query" (`WHERE accession = constant`) will typically take *one* disk hit.  To discuss other queries, please show us the `SELECT`.

**Edit**

With 100M rows, shrinking the disk footprint is important for performance.  There are multiple ways to do it.  I want to focus on  (1) Shrink the size of each column; (2) Avoid implicit overhead in indexes.

Each secondary key implicitly includes the `PRIMARY KEY`.  So, if there are 3 indexes, there are 3 copies of the PK.  That means that the size of the PK is especially important.

I'm recommending something like

```
CREATE TABLE `uniprot` (
  `Accession` VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `DB` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  `Organism` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Gene` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Header` text NOT NULL,
  `Sequence` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Accession`),
  INDEX(Gene),   -- implicitly (Gene, Accession)
  INDEX(Name)    -- implicitly (Organism, Accession)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

And your main queries are

```
SELECT Sequence FROM uniprot WHERE Accession = '...';
SELECT Sequence FROM uniprot WHERE Gene = '...';
SELECT Sequence FROM uniprot WHERE Organism = '...';
```

If `Accession` is really variable length and shorter than to and ascii, then what I suggest brings the length down from 40 bytes * 3 occurrences * 100M rows = 12GB, just for the copies of Accession, down to perhaps 2GB.  I think the savings of 10GB is worth it.  Going to BIGINT would be also be about 2GB (no further savings); going to INT would be about 1GB (more savings, but not much).

Shrinking Gene and Organism to 'reasonable' sizes (if practical) avoids the need for using prefixing, hence allowing the index to work better.  But, you can argue that maybe prefixing will work "well enough" in `INDEX(Gene(11))`.  Let's get some numbers to make the argument one way or another.  What is the average length of `Gene` (and `Organism`)?  How many initial characters in `Gene` are *usually* sufficient to identify a Gene?

Another space question is whether there are a lot of duplicates in Gene and/or Organism.  If so, then "normalizing" those fields would be warranted.  Ditto for Name, Header, and Sequence.

The need for a `JOIN` (or two) if you make surrogates for `Accession` and/or `Gene` is only a slight bit of overhead, not enough to worry about.

Comment: Pretty much what I said. `Don't use "prefix" indexing, it almost never does as well as you might expect.` Based on what? `With those changes, I would not bother switching to a 'surrogate' key` You saying that if he were using a surrogate key with the same engine, that it would be taking 40 bytes for an int column? Last time I checked 40 > 8

Comment: Prefix indexing won't get past the first prefix.  Prefixing sometimes does a bigger scan than necessary.  I don't think the "range" algorithms work well with prefixing.  In general, my experience has been negative.

Comment: A 4-byte `INT UNSIGNED` would be better than a fixed-length 40-byte `CHAR`.  But the example, if changed to `VARCHAR` and `ascii` is about 7 bytes (1-byte length + 6 byte string).  That's not enough bigger than 4 bytes to be worth the extra effort.  (`BIGINT` - 8 bytes - may not be warranted.)

Comment: And a prefix index cannot be "covering" since it leaves out some of the data.

Comment: `And a prefix index cannot be "covering" since it leaves out some of the data.` Of course, but what is the alternative, allow for 255 long indices? With that many rows it will be a huge footprint. `But the example, if changed to VARCHAR and ascii`. Not sure where this came from, my suggestion is to add a bigint unsigned surrogate PK. I have 0 exp with utf8mb4 charsets, so I assume you mean changing this to ascii (utf8)?

Comment: ascii is a 1-byte encoding; utf8 is (up to) 3 bytes; they are _not_ the same.  utf8mb4 is an extension of utf8 and has up to 4 bytes per character.  (The original MySQL utf8 left out some Chinese characters and Emoji.)  The `ascii` characters are a subset of `latin1`, `utf8`, and `utf8mb4` (and most other charsets).

Comment: `CHAR` always allocates the max number of bytes possible.  `VARCHAR` is variable length.  Storing English text in a `VARCHAR` will take the same amount of space regardless of the charset.

Comment: Ok got it on utf8mb4. Not sure how explaining what CHAR and VARCHAR have to do with using a surrogate key over a natural key in this instance, or why index prefixes won't work.

Comment: OK, I elaborated.  And, yes, `INDEX(Gene(11))` _might_ be worth doing.  (The original `main_index` definitely is not.)

Comment: Ya totally agree with dropping that main_index key.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will delete the main_index, and use the ones you suggested. The organism name and gene likely will never be longer then 100, so i ll update those as well. The "sequence" you asked in amino acid sequence, made up by ~25 different characters, and can be as long as 20000 characters, but it is kinda rare to be this long. Any way to compress there?

Comment: Compress -- depends on what language you are using for accessing.  (In any case, make it a BLOB instead of TEXT since "compressed" stuff is not "text".)

Answer (score 0):

First off, as mentioned in the comments I wouldn't use a natural key (Accession), I would opt for a surrogate key (Id), however with 100M rows, that would be a painful alter during which the table will be locked.

With that being said, Accession is already indexed b/c it's a Primary Key so for simple queries, you can't optimize further:

```
select sequence from uniprot where accession="q32p44";
```

If doing look-ups against other columns then your best bet is to add  separate indices for each column:

```
ALTER TABLE uniprot ADD INDEX (Gene(10)), ADD KEY (Organism(10));
```

The goal is to index the uniqueness of the values (cardinality), so if you have a lot of values with somethingsomething1, somethingsomething2, somethingsomething3 then it would be best to go with a prefix of 18+ but no larger than say 30.

Per [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html):

> If names in the column usually differ in the first 10 characters, this index should not be much slower than an index created from the entire name column. Also, using column prefixes for indexes can make the index file much smaller, which could save a lot of disk space and might also speed up INSERT operations.

So the goal is to index the uniqueness (cardinality) but without inflating size on disk.

I would also remove that `main_index` index, as I don't see the benefit as you are not searching on all those columns at the same time, and due to length, will slow down your writes with little gain on the reads.

Be sure to **test** before you run anything on production. Perhaps get a small sampling (1-5% of the dataset) and prefix your queries you plan on running with `explain` to see how MySQL will execute them.

Comment: So what did you end up going with?